# Insert current date time in a column of and keep it constant

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

i am using sql server in making my project with javafx. Their i have a table of purchase and sale. One of the column of both of them is date having current date and time to store them as a record that this transaction has been saved in this time.
Now i am using the that date column with varchar datatype and have using computed column specification with following function:

```
(CONVERT([varchar](25),getdate(),(120)))
```

but when i select records from that table using query

```
SELECT pr.Date, p.Name, pr.Quantity, s.Name, p.Pur_Price
FROM (([Product] AS p
INNER JOIN [Purchase] AS pr ON pr.Product_id=p.Product_id)
INNER JOIN [Supplier] AS s ON s.Supplier_Id=p.Supplier_Id)
WHERE pr.Date>= dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, getdate()-30))
```

but it selects all the records keeping all date records to current date and time. Thanks in advance.
Looking forward for your good replies.

Comment: What's the goal of this query?

Comment: please show us your DDL for the table in question. And DML how you inserted a row in to that table

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Date` column is computed on the fly and not actually stored in the table. So each time you `SELECT` from that table, the expression of the computed column is calculated `(CONVERT([varchar](25),getdate(),(120)))` thus resulting in the same value for all rows.

A fix would be using a `PERSISTED` computed column so that values are actually stored with the table when inserting or updating:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
    OtherColumns INT, 
    [Date] AS (CONVERT([varchar](25), getdate(), 120)) PERSISTED)
```

The problem with this is that non-deterministic expressions can't be persisted, as this error message pops up:

> Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Computed column 'Date' in table
>   'Product' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

You have several other options for this. Please use `DATE` or `DATETIME` columns to store and handle dates and avoid using `VARCHAR` for this as it brings many problems. The following examples use `DATETIME`:

- Use a `DEFAULT` constraint linked to the column with the expression you want:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE Product (
      OtherColumns INT, 
      [Date] DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE())

  INSERT INTO Product (
      OtherColumns) -- Skip the Date column on the INSERT
  VALUES
      (1)

  SELECT * FROM Product

  OtherColumns    Date
  1               2018-12-14 08:49:08.347

  INSERT INTO Product (
      OtherColumns,
      Date)
  VALUES
      (2,
      DEFAULT) -- Or use the keyword DEFAULT to use the default value

  SELECT * FROM Product

  OtherColumns    Date
  1               2018-12-14 08:49:08.347
  2               2018-12-14 08:50:10.070
  ```
- Use a trigger to set the value. This will override any inserted or updated value that the original operation set (as it will execute ***after*** the operation, as stated in it's definition).

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER utrProductSetDate ON Product
      AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
  AS
  BEGIN

      SET NOCOUNT ON

      UPDATE P SET
          Date = GETDATE()
      FROM
          inserted AS I
          INNER JOIN Product AS P ON I.OtherColumns = P.OtherColumns -- Assuming PK or Unique columns join

  END
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you. But i solved my problem by putting my date Column of that table into datetime data type and i my query i have entered the date using getdate() method. It worked for me to save current date and time in my purchase and sale table.